# When do we declare a pointer of an ADT in C and why?

Tags: c, pointers, abstract-data-type

Usually when we create a new structure, with the keyword 'struct' in C, that we may be using in other files than the source file, we use the keyword 'typedef' to define a pointer to the struct;

```
typedef struct struct_name* StructName; // for exmaple
```

why don't we simply define it this way;

```c
typedef struct struct_name StructName; // this time i am not using pointers
```

does using either way differ?

Comment: Yes, they are different, the first form is usually considered bad practice: [typedef is evil](https://discuss.fogcreek.com/joelonsoftware1/10506.html), always prefer the second form.

Comment: Never hide pointer types behind typedefs, this only causes confusion.

Comment: No, it is not preferable to define a *pointer* like this for ADT. Consider the C `FILE` that is a struct - you use `FILE *` everywhere.

Comment: What do you mean by "ADT"? Please read the tag description. the tag [tag:adt] is about an Android plugin.

Comment: @Jabberwocky Normally I would agree, when using plain structures that the user of the structure can dereference directly. But with opaque data structures where one only can reference the data through a set of API functions, then I would argue it doesn't really matter.

Comment: Okay thanks for the help, I got it!

Comment: Be careful when you say things like "Usually when X we use Y".  There are lots of "common" practices out there, but just because a practice is common doesn't mean it's a good idea, and in fact there are a number of common practices that are downright bad.  Old-school C programmers tend to frown on hiding struct types behind typedefs at all (so that's not necessarily a "good" practice), and then when it comes to hiding struct *pointers* behind typedefs, that's generally considered to be a bad idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The big difference is that with the first you can define variables directly, but not with the other.

To simplify, lets say we have two different type-aliases, one for the pointer to the structure and one for the structure itself:

```
typedef struct struct_name* StructNamePtr;
typedef struct struct_name StructName;
```

Now this is possible:

```
StructNamePtr my_pointer_1;
StructName *my_pointer_2;
```

But not this

```
StructName my_struct;  // Will lead to error if `struct_name` truly is an opaque data
                       // structure, and not available to the compiler
```

Note that the definition of the variable `my_pointer_2` is very similar to how you define `FILE` streams, and that's because the C library uses the same technique for that.

Answer (score 3):

The generic argument against typedefs for pointers is that if you use the form

```
typedef struct struct_name *ADT;
```

you cannot declare a function that does not modify the data structure:

```
void some_function(const ADT bar);
```

means `struct struct_name *const bar` i.e. the pointer cannot be pointed to a different value but the pointed-to structure can be modified. If you want to do that, then you need to have **another** typedef for constant types:

```
typedef const struct struct_name *ConstADT;
```

and

```
void some_function(ConstADT bar);
```

and it becomes hard to realize that they're the same type but differently qualified. Then you will soon have all sorts of garbage typedefs like `LPCVOIDPTRCSTR` and everyone will just have a headache.

Answer (score 1):

This typedef

```
typedef struct struct_name* StructName;
```

firstly declares the type `struct struct_name` and secondly the type `struct struct_name*`.

You may rewrite the typedef also the following way

```
struct struct_name typedef  *StructName;
```

To declare a pointer of the type StructName (that is the same as `struct struct_name*`) there is no need to define the structure `struct_name`. That is the type `struct struct_name` may be incomplete.

**So this approach usually used when you need only a pointer of a structure type in some compilation unit**. Here is `StructName` is an alias for the type `struct struct_name *`.

However this approach has a drawback. For example if you will write for example

```
const StructName *pv;
```

then it does not mean

```
const struct struct_name *pv;
```

that is that the pointer points to a constant object.

It means that the pointer itself is constant bit not the pointed object. That is it is equivalent to the following declaration

```
struct struct_name * const pv;
```

If you will need to declare a variable of the type `struct struct_name` you have to write (provided that the structure was already defined)

```
struct struct_name v;
```

but to declare a pointer to an object of the structure you can use either

```
struct struct_name *pv;
```

or

```
StructName pv;
```

This will confuse readers of the code if indeed a variable of the type `struct struct_name` is required in the compilation unit.

This typedef

```
typedef struct struct_name StructName;
```

introduces alias `StructName` for the type `struct struct_name` (not for pointer to an object of the type `struct struct_name` as it was done on the previous typedef).

In this case used names of the type will be consistent through the compilation unit for variable declarations of the type `struct struct_name` and for pointer declarations

```
struct struct_name v;
struct struct_name *pv:
```